AWS API Gateway not passing JSON object to Lambda function
I have created a few functions in Lambda.  I can access all of the GETs through the API Gateway.  I can call them all from Postman or my mobile app.
Now I have created a POST function with C#.  I have tested the function locally in Visual Studio 2022 with the "Mock Lambda Test Tool" and uploaded to AWS Lambda.  The function works as expected when given parameters.
Focusing now on the API Gateway.
If I pass the same parameters through the API Gateway POST then I get the full unfiltered table back which tells me no parameters were detected.
Testing the function I can use the "API Gateway AWS Proxy" template or crop it down to this;
{
  "body": "{\"clubid\":1000}"
}

or roll my own;
{
    {"clubid":1000}
}

I'm completely stumped now!

Ok so in my current function configuration, when I am testing directly against the Lambda Function I must pass in the variables as though they are already wrapped in the proxy.
{
  "body": "{\"clubid\":1000}"
}

but when I pass it to the API Gateway (or from Postman) I pass them in as the JSON poco:
{
  "body": "clubid":1000
}

I hope that helps followers.
